# View disappears when it moves beyond a certain X coordinate

Tags: android

I want to make a view move in front of another one. I used a relative layout in order for the z-order to work as follows.

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="200dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java: When the user touch textView1, the textView2 moves according to the X of the touch event.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        textView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                textView2.setLeft((int) event.getX());
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    }
}
```

But textView2 strangely disappears beyond a certain X coordinate (as if it goes behind a invisible third view) as follows:

```
The beginning:
+-------------------------------+
|                               |
|   +----+                      |
|   |    |                      |
|   |    |                      |
|   +----+                      |
|                               |
+-------------------------------+

Moving to the right..
+-------------------------------+
|                               |
|       +----+                  |
|       |    |                  |
|       |    |                  |
|       +----+                  |
|                               |
+-------------------------------+

.. and starts to disappear at a certain X.
+-------------------------------+
|                               |
|              +--              |
|              |                |
|              |                |
|              +--              |
|                               |
+-------------------------------+
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your padding right is not too important:

```
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

Are you sure it is a good idea to use `setLeft()`. Maybe, it is better to pass by the LayoutParam ?

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(event.getX(), 0, 0, 0);
textView2.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much. But I'm just curious to know why setLeft() doesn't work in this case..

Comment: I don't know why, but the documentation is explicit, it is not a good idea to use this method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLeft%28int%29